# Publishing Same Android App for Different Countries

Tags: android, apk, country, regions, multiple-apk

I've developed an android app that i want to publish on google play store. Issue is that the app won't work same in the different countries so I've to tweak my apk and upload the same android app for different countries.

I've read on Google developer guide site but It doesn't mention any country/region based filters. Any help or suggestion?

[Android Publishing Filters Guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#MultiApks)

I'm using GeoLocation Names in my app. Some regions have 4 Parts address(Street Name, Area Name, City, Country) and some have only 3 (Area, City and Country).

Comment: It's not possible to upload different APKs based on the country to be published. If you really want to do that the only solution would be using different package names. 

I would suggest to handles this in your business logic. Just check, whether a street name is available and use a different layout, string, etc depending on that.

Comment: @sativa Thats exactly what i thought when this issue occurred but this will make my app not so productive based on its functionality to provide user with the info about the street/area in its surrounding. Streets/areas will covers a small radius around the user current location but if i skip the street name it will only widen the surrounding area. This region filter isn't a solution either but I wanted to apply this thing anyway. And what do you mean by uploading with different package name? it won't be same app anymore? correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes it would be a different app, if you use a different package names. Yes, the best way is, to handle this in one app.

Comment: was looking exactly for this, and surprised to see that there's no solution given by play store for this other than  a lot of dirty if-else in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any filter that will help you in your app publication for different regions but I can suggest a different approach for your idea (based on your comment).

"based on its functionality to provide user with the info about the street/area **in its surrounding**. Streets/areas will covers a small radius around the user current location".

You can use the user's current coordinates and set a parameter of some radius lets say 500M and you can show info that is within that circle of 500M radius.

" if i skip the street name it will **only widen the surrounding area**."

By doing this, it won'r really matter if the street or area name was available or not, you'll get your job done anyway.

Comment: any example for help?